# Removing entity from join table. Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with removing an entity which is referenced in a join table.
Here are the three enitie that are linked.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "guest_group")
public class GuestGroup {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "guest_group_id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  @JoinTable(
          name = "guest_group_join",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "guest_group_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "guest_id")
  )
  @OrderColumn(name = "index")
  private Set<Guest> guests;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private NoteGroup noteGroup;

  public void addGuest(Guest guest) {
    this.guests.add(guest);
  }

  public void removeGuest(Guest guest) {
    this.guests.remove(guest);
  }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "note_group")
public class NoteGroup {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "note_group_id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(
          name = "note_group_join",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "note_group_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "note_id")
  )
  @OrderColumn(name = "index")
  private Set<Note> notes;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Guest {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name = "phone_number")
  private String phoneNumber;
}
```

When I try to delete Guest from the guest table using the CrudRepository it gives me this error.

**ERROR: update or delete on table "guest" violates foreign key constraint "fkkougvmcu860mouaacr1shjxy" on table "guest_group_join". Key (id)=(4) is still referenced from table "guest_group_join".**

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when the only thing you have is a `Guest` object hibernate doesn't have any information about dependencies, so that will be impossible. Bah, since this is a `ManyToMany` relationship special handling of removal was always going to be neccessary.

One way, without changing your mapping, would be to in your repository mnethod to delete a guest find the `GuestGroup` by guest you have, and delete it there (which might work with your cascade REMOVE, though test it well to make sure only objects you expect get removed that way - it's possible it'll cascade to every group that has that guest assigned).

A safer way might be to make the mapping bidirectional, remove the cascade removal, and implement methods (either in repository or the entities themselves) to safely add and delete like this:

```
@Entity
public class Guest {

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "guests")
  private List<GuestGroup> guestGroups = new ArrayList<GuestGroup>();

  ...
  
  public void addGuestGroup(GuestGroup group) {
      this.guestGroups.add(group);
      group.getGuests().add(this);
  }

  public void removeGuestGroup(GuestGroup group) {
      this.guestGroups.remove(group);
      group.getGuests().remove(this);
  }
}
```

And same symmetrically on the other side of the relationship if needed.